# sqlite3 error "ValueError: parameters are of unsupported type"

Tags: python, flask, sqlite3-python

I have an sqlite3 table that I created like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE packages (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    description TEXT,
    price DECIMAL(5,2),
    enabled INTEGER DEFAULT 1
);
```

I am trying to query the table as below:

```py
import sqlite3
from flask import current_app, g


def connection():
    if 'db' not in g or not isinstance(g.db, sqlite3.Connection):
        g.db = sqlite3.connect(current_app.config.get('DBPATH'),
            detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES)
        g.db.row_factory = sqlite3.Row

    return g.db


packageid = 6

cur = connection().cursor()

cur.execute("""
    SELECT id
    FROM packages
    WHERE id = :packageid
    """, {'packageid', packageid})
rec = cur.fetchone()
# Omitted logic to handle rec being None or not None
```

When I run the code above, it fails with `ValueError: parameters are of unsupported type` for line  16.

Why do I get this error? `id` is an `INTEGER` in sqlite3, and `packageid` is an `int` in python. I don't see why these two types are incompatible.

Comment: `{'packageid', packageid}` You probably meant this to be a dict, but it's actually a set, because you used a comma instead of a colon.

Comment: `dict`, `list`, `tuple`, `generator` are supported, `set` no. Are you running python <3.12? I got `sqlite3.ProgrammingError: parameters are of unsupported type`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the problem is not the type of your variable. If you take a look at the documentation for the `Cursor.execute` method (available [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute)) you'll see that it expects a dictionary or a sequence as the second argument.

In your code the second parameter is actually a `set` (probably a typo.. been there, trust me). Just change it from `{'packageid', packageid}` to `{'packageid': packageid}` and it will probably work.